# Creating multidimensional array from dynamic form in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to capture values from inputs and put them in JQuery object instead of having to deal with PHP indexing.

This is the form

```
<form name="second_form" id="second_form" action="#" method="POST">         
    <a href="#" id="AddChampion" onclick="return false;">Add Champion</a>
        <div id="ChampionInput">
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <input id="obj" type="hidden" name="obj">
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

My script that I'm trying to use to recreate the array:

```
$("#second_form").submit(function(event) {   
    var object = [];        
    $('.Champion').each(function() {
        var champion = {
            'name': $(this).find(".ChampionInput").val(),
            'change': $(this).find("input:radio:checked").val(),
            'General_Description': [],
            'General_Change':[]
        };
        $(this).find('.GeneralChange').each(function() {            champion.General_Description.push($(this).children(".GeneralChangeDescription").val());
            champion.General_Change.push($(this).children(".General_Change").val());
        });         
        object.push(champion);
    });
    object = JSON.stringify(object);
    $('#obj').val(object); //Sending object to hidden input   
});
```

And here is the way I used to create this PHP array which messes up indexing when I delete some inputs when creating the form

```
 foreach($_POST['champion'] as $champion){
                if(isset($_POST['Release'][$ChampionNumber])){
                    $_POST['Release'][$ChampionNumber]=='New' ? $champions[$champion]['New']=1 : $champions[$champion]['New']=0;

                    $_POST['Release'][$ChampionNumber]=='Rework' ? $champions[$champion]['Rework']=1 : $champions[$champion]['Rework']=0;

                }
                if(!empty($_POST['GeneralChangeDescription'][$ChampionNumber])){
                    foreach($_POST['GeneralChangeDescription'][$ChampionNumber] as $indexGeneral=>$GeneralChangeDescription){
                    $GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1] =ucfirst(trim($GeneralChangeDescription));
                    if(substr($GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1], -1)!='.'){
                        $GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1] = $GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1].'.';
                    }
                    $GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1] = preg_replace('/\s\/\s/','/',$GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1]);
                    $GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1] = preg_replace( '/(\.?\d\/?%?)+/', '<strong>$0</strong>', $GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1]);
                    $GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1] = preg_replace( '/\b\w+\.(jpg|png|gif)/', '', $GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1]);                   
                    $champions[$champion]['General']['Change'][] =  $GeneralChangeDescriptions[$ChampionNumber+1][$indexGeneral+1];
                    $champions[$champion]['General']['Type'][] = $_POST['GeneralChange'][$ChampionNumber][$indexGeneral];

                    }
                }

                $ChampionNumber++;              
            }
```

Removing champions

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.Remove',function(){
    var champion = $(this).closest('.Champion');
    var id = champion.data("id");
    var nextChampion = champion;

    while((nextChampion = nextChampion.next()).length != 0){

        nextChampion.attr("data-id",id++);
        nextChampion.children('.ChampionInput').attr('placeholder','Champion '+ id);

    }
    championNumber=id+1;
    championNumberArray=id;
    champion.remove();
});
```

Removing changes

```
$('div#ChampionInput').on('click', 'a.RemoveGeneralChange',function(){
        $(this).closest('.GeneralChange').remove();
    });
```

Here is how my array looks like in PHP: https://i.stack.imgur.com/488Ah.png and I want to get array looking like that after sending JQuery object through hidden input in form and obtaining it in PHP. Here is how my JQuery object looks like right now https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRi6a.jpg which is not even close.

Here is also JSfiddle of form creation: jsfiddle.net/g50zd384/

Comment: What is false in your generated jQuery object? Obtain your data in PHP an modify your array in PHP. You can't create the same syntax in JSON-objects and in PHP arrays.

Comment: @Sim Thank you for response, the problem with syntax is that my code that I later on use to display this data / save this data is using that multidimensional PHP array so I wanted to achive something like that so I wouldn't have to change the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need that array, so create it in PHP after sending the form:

```
$array;
for($i = 1; $i <= count($_POST['champion']); $i++) {
    $champion = $_POST['champion'][$i];
    $array[$champion]['General'] = $_POST['GeneralChangeDescription'][$i];
    $array[$champion]['Type'] = $_POST['GeneralChange'][$i];
    $array[$champion]['Release'] = $_POST['Release'][$i];
}
```

Your form should be created with this names:

```
championNumber = 1;
    championNumberArray = 0;
    $('a#AddChampion').on('click',function(){
        $('div#ChampionInput').append(
        '<div class="Champion">\
             <br>\
             <input type="text" class="ChampionInput" name="champion['+championNumber+']" placeholder="Champion '+championNumber+'">\
             <datalist id="champions"></datalist>\
             <input type="radio" name="Release['+championNumber+']" value="New">New\
             <input type="radio" name="Release['+championNumber+']" value="Rework">Rework\
             <input type="radio" name="Release['+championNumber+']" value="None" checked>None\
             <a href="#" class="AddGeneralChange" data-id="'+championNumber+'" onclick="return false;">Add General Change</a>\
             <div class="GeneralChanges">\
             </div>\
             <br>\
         <div>');
        championNumber++;
    });
    $('div#ChampionInput').on('click','a.AddGeneralChange', function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $(this).siblings('.GeneralChanges').append(
           '<div class="GeneralChange">\
                <textarea type="text" size="20" rows="3" cols="50" maxlength="500" class="GeneralChangeDescription" name="GeneralChangeDescription['+id+'][]" placeholder="Enter General Change Description"></textarea>\
                <select class="General_Change" name="GeneralChange['+id+'][]">\
                   <option value="buff">Buff</option>\
                   <option value="nerf">Nerf</option>\
                   <option value="new">New</option>\
                   <option value="change">Change</option>\
                   <option value="bugfix">Bugfix</option>\
                </select>\
            </div>');
    });
```

It is important, that you name your inputs in this way!
..not the best way, but better than sending json data in a hidden input form. I hope this could help you.

Comment: alright but what happens if someone would lets say create 3 champions [0] [1] [2] and add 1 general change to each one of those champions so [0][0] [1][0] [2][0] and then he would delete just the second champion it would mess up the array because it would be [0][0] and [2][0] instead of [0][0] and [1][0]

Comment: I've added to this post my functions that delete champions and changes it fixes indexing when you delete champion so [0] [1] [2] if you delete middle one indexing will be [0] [1] it doesnt work though for subcategories/changes with 2 dimensions